# Why is metacity still my display manager instead of awesome?

Tags: gnome, awesome, display-manager

I am trying to stop using unity and make awesome my default display manager while still having gnome as my default desktop environment. I am following the instructions at [this page](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quickly_Setting_up_Awesome_with_Gnome#Ubuntu_11.10). I did however base my gnome session on the gnome classic session.
I created the following files:

/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-nounity.session:

```
[GNOME Session]
Name=GNOME no Unity
RequiredComponents=gnome-panel;gnome-settings-daemon;
RequiredProviders=windowmanager;notifications;launcher;panel;
DefaultProvider-windowmanager=awesome
DefaultProvider-notifications=notify-osd
DefaultProvider-launcher=unity-2d-launcher
DefaultProvider-panel=cairo-dock
IsRunnableHelper=/usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-check-accelerated
FallbackSession=gnome-fallback
DesktopName=GNOME
```

/usr/share/applications/awesome.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Awesome
Comment=The awesome launcher!
TryExec=awesome
Exec=awesome
```

/usr/share/xsessions/gnome-nounity.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GNOME Classic no unity
Comment=This session logs you into GNOME with the traditional panel
Exec=gnome-session --session=gnome-nounity
TryExec=gnome-session
Icon=
Type=Application
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-3.0
```

I am choosing `GNOME no Unity` at login. But somehow metacity will keep starting. Is there something wrong with my configuration? Or is there some other reason metacity is starting. Maybe gnome-fallback is launching, but why and how to check? Please help me out, I really do want my display manager to be `awesome` ;)

Comment: take the isrrunnablehelper line out - does this help?  Can you normally run Unity/Gnome-Shell or does it fallback to Unity-2D / Gnome-fallback?

Comment: I removed the isrunnablehelpen, this does not resolve the issue. I did start a normal GNOME session and now it seems to be using lightdm. I have been experimenting with various display managers, I did not know lightdm changes the default for GNOME. But at least its not using gnome-fallback which would be using metacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Turns out notify-osd has a bug as described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/885939). It does not have a .desktop launcher. Removing notify-osd from my session caused awesome to load properly. I found these errors in ~/.xsession-errors.